# CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set when using buildozer in linux

Tags: python, android, cmake, kivy, buildozer

I was using buildozer to package my app. Because I need to use package scipy, so I have to install fortran thins. After I successfully installed. The package process displays another error. shortly:

```
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

when I use `cmake -version` to check its version, it displays,`cmake version 3.10.2`.
I have seen many answers, but it either uses Java to develop, or develops on windows system. Because I have never develop the app before, it's hard for me to understand their thoughts. Anyone can help me? or give me a direction...

```
> [DEBUG]:   -> running rm -rf CMakeFiles/ CMakeCache.txt [DEBUG]:   ->
> running cmake
> /home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/lapack/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/lapack -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=1 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/lapack/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/lapack/build/install
> -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_ARM_NEON=ON -DENABLE_NEON=ON -DCBLAS=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON [DEBUG]:        -- Android: Targeting API '28' with architecture 'arm64', ABI 'arm64-v8a', and
> processor 'aarch64' [DEBUG]:        -- The Fortran compiler
> identification is GNU 4.9.0 [DEBUG]:        CMake Error at
> /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/Platform/Android/Determine-Compiler-NDK.cmake:97
> (message): [DEBUG]:          Android: No toolchain for ABI 'arm64-v8a'
> found in the NDK: [DEBUG]: [DEBUG]:           
> /home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c [DEBUG]:
> [DEBUG]:        Call Stack (most recent call first): [DEBUG]:         
> /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/Platform/Android/Determine-Compiler.cmake:39
> (include) [DEBUG]:         
> /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/Platform/Android-Determine-C.cmake:1
> (include) [DEBUG]:         
> /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:27
> (include) [DEBUG]:          CMakeLists.txt:3 (project) [DEBUG]:
> [DEBUG]: [DEBUG]:        CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after
> EnableLanguage [DEBUG]:        -- Configuring incomplete, errors
> occurred! [DEBUG]:        See also
> "/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/lapack/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/lapack/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> Exception in thread background thread for pid 9155: Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916,
> in _bootstrap_inner
>     self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
>     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/home/jago/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 1683, in
> wrap
>     fn(*rgs, **kwargs)   File "/home/jago/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2662, in
> background_thread
>     handle_exit_code(exit_code)   File "/home/jago/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2349, in
> fn
>     return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)   File "/home/jago/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 905, in
> handle_command_exit_code
>     raise exc sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:
> 
>   RAN: /usr/bin/cmake
> /home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/lapack/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/lapack -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=1 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/lapack/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/lapack/build/install
> -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_ARM_NEON=ON -DENABLE_NEON=ON -DCBLAS=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON
> 
>   STDOUT:
> -- Android: Targeting API '28' with architecture 'arm64', ABI 'arm64-v8a', and processor 'aarch64'
> -- The Fortran compiler identification is GNU 4.9.0 CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/Platform/Android/Determine-Compiler-NDK.cmake:97
> (message):   Android: No toolchain for ABI 'arm64-v8a' found in the
> NDK:
> 
>     /home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
> 
> Call Stack (most recent call first):  
> /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/Platform/Android/Determine-Compiler.cmake:39
> (include)  
> /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/Platform/Android-Determine-C.cmake:1
> (include)  
> /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:27
> (include)   CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
> 
> 
> CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/lapack/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/lapack/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> 
> 
>   STDERR:
> 
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>     "__main__", mod_spec)   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>     exec(code, run_globals)   File "/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
> line 1294, in <module>
>     main()   File "/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py",
> line 18, in main
>     ToolchainCL()   File "/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
> line 728, in __init__
>     getattr(self, command)(args)   File "/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
> line 151, in wrapper_func
>     build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)   File "/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py",
> line 213, in build_dist_from_args
>     args, "ignore_setup_py", False   File "/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py",
> line 596, in build_recipes
>     recipe.build_arch(arch)   File "/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/lapack/__init__.py",
> line 53, in build_arch
>     _env=env)   File "/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py",
> line 167, in shprint
>     for line in output:   File "/home/jago/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 953, in
> next
>     self.wait()   File "/home/jago/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 879, in
> wait
>     self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)   File "/home/jago/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 905, in
> handle_command_exit_code
>     raise exc sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:
> 
>   RAN: /usr/bin/cmake
> /home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/lapack/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/lapack -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=1 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/lapack/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/lapack/build/install
> -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_ARM_NEON=ON -DENABLE_NEON=ON -DCBLAS=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON
> 
>   STDOUT:
> -- Android: Targeting API '28' with architecture 'arm64', ABI 'arm64-v8a', and processor 'aarch64'
> -- The Fortran compiler identification is GNU 4.9.0 CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/Platform/Android/Determine-Compiler-NDK.cmake:97
> (message):   Android: No toolchain for ABI 'arm64-v8a' found in the
> NDK:
> 
>     /home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c
> 
> Call Stack (most recent call first):  
> /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/Platform/Android/Determine-Compiler.cmake:39
> (include)  
> /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/Platform/Android-Determine-C.cmake:1
> (include)  
> /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:27
> (include)   CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
> 
> 
> CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/lapack/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/lapack/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> 
> 
>   STDERR:
> 
> # Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2
> --requirements=python3,kivy,plyer,numpy,matplotlib,scipy --arch arm64-v8a --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always
> --storage-dir="/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a"
> --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
> # ENVIRONMENT:
> #     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
> #     HOSTTYPE = 'x86_64'
> #     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
> #     PULSE_SERVER = '/mnt/wslg/PulseServer'
> #     LANG = 'C.UTF-8'
> #     DISPLAY = ':0'
> #     OLDPWD = '/mnt/c/Users/14750'
> #     WSL_INTEROP = '/run/WSL/632_interop'
> #     WSL_DISTRO_NAME = 'Ubuntu-18.04'
> #     USER = 'jago'
> #     WAYLAND_DISPLAY = 'wayland-0'
> #     PWD = '/home/jago'
> #     HOME = '/home/jago'
> #     NAME = 'onlyfools44u'
> #     https_proxy = 'https://172.18.32.1:7890'
> #     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
> #     http_proxy = 'http://172.18.32.1:7890'
> #     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
> #     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
> #     SHLVL = '1'
> #     LOGNAME = 'jago'
> #     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/mnt/wslg/runtime-dir'
> #     PATH = ('/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/jago/.local/bin:/home/jago/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Program
> '  'Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/bin:/mnt/c/Program ' 
> 'Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/jre/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program
> '  'Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program
> Files/NVIDIA '  'Corporation/NVIDIA ' 
> 'NvDLISR:/mnt/d/Bandizip/:/mnt/d/Git/cmd:/mnt/d/platform-tools:/mnt/c/Users/14750/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/14750/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/:/mnt/c/Users/14750/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/d/PyCharm/bin:/snap/bin:/home/jago/.local/bin/')
> #     WSLENV = ''
> #     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
> #     _ = '/home/jago/.local/bin/buildozer'
> #     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/jago/.buildozer/android/packages'
> #     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
> #     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/jago/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
> #     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
> #     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
> #
> # Buildozer failed to execute the last command
> # The error might be hidden in the log above this error
> # Please read the full log, and search for it before
> # raising an issue with buildozer itself.
> # In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Do you have a C compiler installed on your local system? If yes, try setting the environment variable "CC" to your compiler executable.

Comment: Please, do not use *blockquote* formatting for the error log. This formatting doesn't preserve **newlines**, making the output hard to read. Instead, format the log in the same way as a code. Would you properly format the log, you will easily find the **first error message**: `Android: No toolchain for ABI 'arm64-v8a'
found in the NDK`. Exactly that error message you should resolve first. Trying to fix error messages other that the first one in most cases is the waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade cmake to 3.16.8 can solve it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).